# How to get distance between two atoms using for loop?

Tags: biopython

I have one PDB  structure. This structure has 13 residues. I have to find the distance between two atoms(only C,O,N,S) using for loop. First I have to find the distance between first and second residue. after that first and third residue.up to first and 13 th residue and so on. How can I write the python script using for loop?

Comment: You can't find the distance between two atoms, you can only get a probability distribution of how far they _might_ be apart :-)

Comment: we can find the distance between two atoms using minus operator in biopython.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the xyz coordinates you can calculate distances between each atom. First you'll have to parse the PDB file and store the coordinates. Then just iterate over the list of atoms (for atom in list_of_atoms) and calculate the euclidean distance between them..

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Three_dimensions

Biopython's Bio.PDB module also allows such calculation easily.

Comment: Dear friend, Thank you very much for your comment. I have written a Biopython script to find the distance between two atoms.from Bio.PDB.PDBParser import PDBParser    
  pdbfn ='C:/pdb/apoe4.pdb'
  parser = PDBParser(PERMISSIVE=1)   
  structure = parser.get_structure("2zvw", pdbfn)

  model = structure[0]
  chain = model['A']
  
  residue1 = chain[1]
  residue2 = chain[2]

  atom1 = residue1['C']
  atom2 = residue2['C']

 
 distance = atom1-atom2
 print(distance)